# Microsoft Access 2018 - adding new data entries using a form

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a form, in which I want it to create a new row of data in my table. However, whenever I input something into this form instead of creating a new data entry, it picks an existing one and modifies it.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you actions you take when you *"input something into the form"* Are you creating a new record first?

Answer (score 0):

If the form is bound to a table; then one must advance to a new blank row.  There are several form types: In a Continuous or Datasheet form - one simply scrolls to the bottom to find the new blank row. In a Single Record View form - one must use the record selector in the bottom frame of the form to advance to a new record or add a button that advances to a new record/row.  There is also an option in form properties to be a Data Entry Form that will only open to a new record.